# numpy's interp function - how to find a value of x for a given value of y?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have an array of values of x (in increasing order) and the corresponding y values. Numpy's interp function takes in the X value, and the x and y arrays. How do I get the value of X for a given value of Y?? Eg if y = 0, x = ?.

Cheers!

code:

```
j = (((1840/(2*pi))**0.5)*exp(phi)) - 1.0 #y axis, phi is a 1-D array
t = linspace(0, 40, 100) #x axis
a = interp(<x-value>,t,j) # this gives me the corresponding y value!
```

So what should I do to get the x value for a given y value!!

Comment: Do you need it for this specific function, or for the general case? Bear in mind that, if the function is not invertible, there might exist multiple `x` for the same `y`.

Comment: Your eample should be more minimal, I had to replace `phi` by `t`, and add `from numpy import exp, linspace, interp, pi`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`y_interp = np.interp(x_interp, x, y)` yields an interpolation of the function `y_interp = f(x_interp)` based on a previous interpolation `y = f(x)`, where x.size = y.size, x_interp.size = y_interp.size.

If you want x as a function of y, you have to construct the inverse function. As @NPE indicated, you have to make sure that x and y are always increasing. An easy way to check this is to use

```
np.all(np.diff(x) > 0)
np.all(np.diff(y) > 0)
```

Now finding the inverse function is actually very simple: you have to reverse the roles of x and y (since we deal with interpolations).

With my notations: `x_value = np.interp(y_value, x, y)`.

With your notations: `x_value = interp(y_value, j, t)`

Comment: Inverting the function did the trick! Yes @NPE I needed it for this specific function. Luckily the value of j falls throughout increasing x so I just switched the roles and got the answer.

Thanks a lot I appreciate it :)

Comment: Just wondering: if `y_interp = np.interp(x_interp, x, y)`, shouldn't it be `x_value = np.interp(y_value, y, x)`, instead of `x_value = np.interp(y_value, x, y)`? (just as `interp(y_value, j, t)` is the inverse of `interp(<x-value>,t,j)`)

Answer (score 0):

When using Numpy make sure you're using a Numpy array: `np.array([])`

```
#x data array
x_data = np.array([1,2,3,4])
    
#y data array
y_data = np.array([1,3,2,1])

#the known max y value is 3
y_max = 3
            
# sort the arrays
order = y_data.argsort()
y_data = y_data[order]
x_data = x_data[order]
        

# call the interpolation function but reverse the array datasets to find the corresponding x value       
x = np.interp(y_max, y_data, x_data,  left=None, right=None, period=None)
```

For this example the result is x = 2 when max y = 3. The maximum is (2,3).

Furthermore you can append data to a numpy array: `x_data = np.append(x_data, appendedValue)`